# How to import .Net DateTime and TimeSpan in Excel via Json and Power Query

Tags: json, excel, datetime, powerquery, timespan

Short version: **How do you import data with .Net DateTime or TimeSpan types to Excel tables via Json and Power Query?** I don't get it to work.

More details: I have sparse data (int values logged sparsely in time) that I want to import as tables and graphs in Excel. In my C# code it's represented as Dictionary<**DateTime**, int>. I export the data to a Json file (using System.Text.Json) and import it to Excel via a Power Query. In Power Query the DateTime ends up as a text column (looks like 0001-07-24T01:05:45 in the preview). I change the type to Date/Time and all seems well (looks like 0001-07-24 01:05:45 in the preview). But when I save and load it to a table, the column is blank. What's going on?

I tried the same thing with **TimeSpan** instead. Json couldn't serialize TimeSpan so I just used .ToString() before serializing it. In Power Query I converted the values to Duration and when I loaded it to tables it actually worked... although I couldn't get the sorting to work. I could only sort it A->Z, not by time, even though Excel obviously understood that they were times (the graph was sparse as expected).

Sorry if this seems like an Excel / Power Query question, but it's related to the two .Net types and I thought there must be many .Net programmers that have done this before.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have **0001-07-24T01:05:45** in powerquery, formatted as date/time it will show you

[image]

and load into excel as blank because there is no year **0001** in Excel. You need to set the year to be something else

This adds a new column where 0001 becomes 2022

```
= Table.AddColumn(#"PriorStepName", "Custom", each DateTime.FromText(Text.Replace(Text.From([ColumnNameHere]),"0001","2020")),type datetime)
```

or this, which replaces 0001 with 2020, in place

```
= Table.TransformColumns(#"PriorStepName",{{"ColumnNameHere", each DateTime.FromText(Text.Replace(Text.From(_),"0001","2020")),type datetime}})
```

Comment: Ok. That's absurd. I'm sure that year 0001 was just as real as 2020. But thank you! It really solved the problem.

Comment: In the 1900 date system, the first day that is supported is January 1, 1900.
In the 1904 date system, the first day that is supported is January 1, 1904